# Can not move animated objects

Tags: animation, transforms

I tried creating a small animation for a piece of furniture i have in my room. It is a table, which you can rotate twice, so that the surface doubles. I have succesfully created said principle in a blender animation, but now i wonder, how to move the whole thing. If i just select everything and move it, the Animation get´s screwed up because of the keyframes. If i create an empty as a parent for everything, the same happens. Even delta transform still screws up the animation.
The animation works with 2 rotation axis (represented by the arrows) which i defined as the parents of the table-covers with constrains. The lower cover, only has to rotate once, so it`s parent stays the vertical arrow, but the upper cover has to rotate twice around different axis, so i change it´s parent on frame 10 to the second axis.

I hope you have some tips on how to fix this. Also, i don´t know, how to post my .blend file here :D

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ click on the link and follow the instruction, so you can provide your blend file

Comment: Hello :). If you find the time, please add some images to illustrate the issue. Not everybody can download a .blend.